# Logic Pro X - Arrangment Markers - how to stop them affecting one track

Tags: logic-pro, multitrack

Fairly new to Logic. I am trying to do something which I am hoping is possible as it seems logical. I feel Logic should do logical things. What I am trying to do is create a track from a track that I am using as a guide. I am doing this both because I need to create a backing track, and also as it's a good way to learn logic. So I have imported an mp3 from a song I want to copy, and I am creating the different instruments for the different sections of the track. Keeping the original track as a guide is very useful as I can constantly check if I am doing a good job, by unmuting and muting it again. So, the problem I have is that I have recently started using Arrangement Markers and I would like to be able to copy the various sections (chorus, verse, etc...) by dragging the markers which is an useful feature of Logic. The problem I have is that when I drag the markers, logic picks up all of the tracks underneath the marker and copies them. This is fine for most of the track that I want copied, but I want the markers to ignore my ''guide track'' as this track needs to remain the same so that I can keep using it as a guide. I am not sure how to do this. I have tried ''locking'' the track, which you would have thought it would be logical that locking it would prevent markers from affecting it, but unfortunately Logic is completely logical here and it does indeed affect the track even if you lock it. So, my question is: Is there any way to make markers ''ignore'' a track?

Many thanks,

d